# How to do sum(max(...))?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my raw data:

```
   Site    IP        Visits    Age (in hours)
1  uu.com  1.2.3.4   10        3                  
2  vv.com  2.9.7.5   2         4
3  kk.com  2.9.7.5   8         24
4  uu.com  1.2.3.4   12        24                  
5  vv.com  2.9.7.5   10        24
6  kk.com  2.9.7.5   8         48
```

I have build a pivot table like this in Google spreadsheet:

```
   Col. A    Col. B   MAX of Visits   MAX of Age
1  1.2.3.4   uu.com   12              24    
2  2.9.7.5   kk.com   8               48
3            vv.com   10              24
```

When I ask Google Spreadsheet to give the totals, I get the following result:

```
   Col. A             Col. B   MAX of Visits   MAX of Age
1  1.2.3.4            uu.com   12              24    
2  Total for 1.2.3.4           12              24
3  2.9.7.5            kk.com   8               48
4                     vv.com   10              24
5  Total for 2.9.7.5           10              48
```

This is not what I'm expecting because I want the SUM('Max of visits') as total.
Clearly, this is the final pivot table I want:

```
   Col. A             Col. B   MAX of Visits   MAX of Age
1  1.2.3.4            uu.com   12              24    
2  Total for 1.2.3.4           12              24
3  2.9.7.5            kk.com   8               48
4                     vv.com   10              24
5  Total for 2.9.7.5           18              48
```

Notice on line `5` , column `'Max of Visits'`, I want **18** and not **10** as Google Spreadsheet gives me.

How can I acheive that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(DATA!C1:F7, "SELECT C, MAX(E), MAX(F) GROUP BY C PIVOT D")
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Remark

In order to get the summation, I simply added a summation for the consecutive columns (see example).

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [SUM and MAX in PIVOT TABLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdFFKYXZUT0NTdDhZMThzc3k2SEVOUmc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Tks for your useful answer.Actually, I'd like to perform this: `SELECT D,C,SUM(MAX(E)) FROM <DATA> GROUP BY D,C`

Comment: @Alex The <DATA> is contained in the SELECT statement....Quote from Google Query Language: `The "from" clause has been eliminated from the language.`

Comment: You're right, but I have tried this `SELECT D,C,SUM(MAX(E)) GROUP BY D,C` and got `#VALUE` error.

Comment: @Alex Haha, added a summation below the result (didn't you see that....haha). There's no other way. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I did see the summation ;)

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
=MAX(Start Cell:End Cell)
```

Here is a demo:
[image: =MAX(Start Cell:End Cell)]